# Error during package installation from testpypi

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py

I wrote a library package and uploaded it to pypi.On trying to install it using the pip command, I am getting an error.

The **setup.py** file has install_requires with the below:

`install_requires=['requests>=2.26.0', 'multipledispatch>=1.0.0']`,

**requires.txt** file also has :

`requests>=2.26.0 multipledispatch>=1.0.0`

however, while trying to install using pip command, I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests>=2.26.0 (from versions: 2.5.4.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests>=2.26.0
```

If I try to install locally and again run the pip command, the package gets installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+test.pypi.org

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple`. `extra-index-url` for `pypi.org` is a must here.